# How to swap values of two string variables without a temp variable?

Tags: c#, .net, string, swap

For example, I have two string variables:

```
string a = " Hello ";
string b = " World ";
```

How can I swap it without a temporary variable?

I found an example, but it used a third variable for the length of `a`:

```
int len1 = a.Length;
a = a + b;
b = a.Substring(0, len1);
a = a.Substring(len1);
```

How can I do that?

UPD, suggested solution for decimal data type, in ma case i've asked about string data type.

Comment: first question is. Why do you need to do such thing?

Comment: @Steve It's probably some sort of interview question

Comment: I think you could use `Interlocked.Exchange` for that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/f2090ex9(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: you have your answer already. no need of any other thing

Comment: Without any further information, I would say the best way is to avoid not using a third variable. There are many (horrible) ways of doing it, but appart from producing unreadable code, cannot see what will be the benefits

Comment: @PavneetSingh  It says in the question why he's not satisfied with that answer

Comment: @SamIam yeah man, i eyes are shutting down i didn't even looked at length,it's 1 am here :P ,length property could have been used dynalically , anyway  nice answer buddy and great efforts guys. thumbs-up

Comment: @S.Akbari hi, yes,good resolve, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How do I swap two strings without using a temporary variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818289/how-do-i-swap-two-strings-without-using-a-temporary-variable)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen i was look another resolve what I was find for my target, may be, you can flag it like a duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swap two variables without using a temporary variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804706/swap-two-variables-without-using-a-temporary-variable)

Comment: @victortv no, this solution for decimals, I need solution for strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SubString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) without using a temp variable, like this:

```
string a = " Hello ";
string b = " World ";

a = a + b;//" Hello  World "
b = a.Substring(0, (a.Length - b.Length));//" Hello "
a = a.Substring(b.Length);//" World "
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use some other means of swapping.

```
string stringOne = "one";
string stringTwo = "two";

stringOne = stringOne + stringTwo;
stringTwo = stringOne.Substring(0, (stringOne.Length - stringTwo.Length));
stringOne = stringOne.Substring(stringTwo.Length);

// Prints stringOne: two stringTwo: one
Console.WriteLine("stringOne: {0} stringTwo: {1}", stringOne, stringTwo);
```

Comment: I don't believe that will compile

Answer (score 0):

```
   string str1 = "First";
        string str2 = "Second";
        str1 = (str2 = str1 + str2).Substring(str1.Length);
        str2 = str2.Substring(0,str1.Length-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fond of doing it this way although underneath it's using resources to make it fully thread-safe, and I wouldn't be surprised if it was using a local  variable behind the scenes.

```
string str1 = "First";
string str2 = "Second";
str2 = System.Interlocked.Exchange(ref str1, str2);
```